# Python CV2 video not playable after python process is killed

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, process

I use CV2 to capture my monitor, when I stop the script via Pycharm or CTRL + C, I can play the video, if instead I kill the Python process, I am not able to play the video.

Do you know why this happens maybe? I thought that it does not matter how you end script (with CTRL + C or by killing the python process), but looks like I am wrong.

Thank you in advance

Comment: same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72528598/save-video-via-python-on-windows-logoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes! you are doing it wrong that you killed the process since there is no time left for program to create usable form of clip which you can run.
try to use stop via #PYCHARM or make a stop code.
thanks.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! Do you by any chance have any idea on how to create a stop code?

Comment: u can use scheduler there are several scheduler available in python there are options available for resuming and pausing and stop and start the scheduled task.